# Bayes theorem and application

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

A pregnancy test is accurate 97% of the time when someone is pregnant and 98% accurate when someone is not. Assuming that 60% of people who take the test are pregnant, and that someone tests positive twice in a row, what is the probability they actually are pregnant?

I think this is application of Bayes theorem but I don't know how to incorporate it in above situation?

Comment: You're right that Bayes theorem is the right thing to go for. So, what numbers do you need to apply the theorem? What probabilities appear in the formula?

Comment: Have a look for base rate fallacy, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_rate_fallacy

Comment: Translate those percentages into statements of conditional probability and see if they can be placed into Bayes' theorem.

Comment: @Semoi The base rate in this case is high enough, and the accuracy of the test good enough (at least when doing it twice in a row) that this doesn't apply.

Comment: P(test is positive/pregnant) = 0.97; p(test negative /pregnant) =0.03 p(test negative / not pregnant) = 0.98 , p(test positive /not pregnant) =0.02 . P(pregnant) = 0.60 now we want p(pregnant/twice positive test)? I am not getting how to incorporate two positive results?   @Arthur

Comment: @Arthur: The **calculation** using Bayes theorem is the same. The numbers do not matter.

Comment: @Arthur can you help me to write down formula for this?

Comment: @Arthur answer came as 0.60

Answer (score 2):

Let $+$ denote a positive test, and $P$ denote being pregnant.

We are given the prior $p(P)=0.6$ and $p(+|P)=0.97$ and $p(+|\neg P)=0.98$. Hence $$p(P|+)=\frac{p(+|P)p(P)}{p(+|P)p(P)+p(+|\neg P)p(\neg P)}$$ $$=\frac{0.97\times0.6}{0.97\times0.6+0.02\times0,4}=0.9864$$ That now becomes the prior for the 2nd test so we have $$p(P|++)=\frac{0.97\times0.9864}{0.97\times0.9864+0.02\times0.0136}=0.9997$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=A_1\cap A_2$ be the event that two tests are positive. And $H_1$ denote being pregnant, $H_2$ - not to be pregnant. Assumed that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are conditionally independent for a single person, so 
$$
\mathbb P(A \mid H_1)=\mathbb P(A_1 \mid H_1)\times \mathbb P(A_2 \mid H_1) = 0.97^2,
$$ 
$$
\mathbb P(A \mid H_2)=\mathbb P(A_1 \mid H_2)\times \mathbb P(A_2 \mid H_2) = 0.02^2,
$$ 
and Bayes formula gives 
$$
\mathbb P(H_1 \mid A) = \frac{\mathbb P(H_1)\times \mathbb P(A \mid H_1)}{\mathbb P(H_1)\times \mathbb P(A \mid H_1)+\mathbb P(H_2)\times \mathbb P(A \mid H_2)} = \frac{0.6\times 0.97^2}{0.6\times 0.97^2+0.4\times 0.02^2}=0.999716664.
$$